# How do I install ncurses header files?

Tags: dependencies, ncurses

I was trying to configure the kernel and I got the following error. Can somebody please tell me what I should do?

```
root@nitr-desktop:/usr/src/linux# make menuconfig
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Comment: Try installing first libncurses5: sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev

Answer (score 118):

Open up your terminal and install libncurses-dev by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

Comment: Not found. This should be ncurses-dev as in the answer below.

Comment: @user643722: What's the problem? `apt-cache show libncurses-dev` yields `N: Can't select versions from package 'libncurses-dev' as it is purely virtual`, which means I could install it like the answer says.

Comment: `libncurses-dev` works for me.

Comment: I know this is ubuntu, but it's still my top result for debian searches... debian uses libncurses5-dev

Comment: I got a `cannot find -lncursesw` which I solved using the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/907500/121101): `apt install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`. Upvote it too.

Answer (score 23):

Above problem solved now. all I did was:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
```

Comment: It says `Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'`. But I specifically need `libncurses-dev` instead of `libncurses5-dev`.

Answer (score 14):

### *Tested on Ubuntu 17.04*

You should install `libncurses5-dev` **and `libncursesw5-dev`**:

```
apt install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

References: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-install-ncurses-library-headers-on-debian-ubuntu-centos-fedora/