# How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, cmake

I am trying to install latest `cmake` in my linux box and I am always getting the below exception -

```
userName@phx5qa01c-4e23:~/build$ wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
--2013-10-08 14:39:55--  http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
Resolving www.cmake.org... 66.194.253.19
Connecting to www.cmake.org|66.194.253.19|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2013-10-08 14:40:17--  (try: 2)  http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
Connecting to www.cmake.org|66.194.253.19|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2013-10-08 14:40:40--  (try: 3)  http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
Connecting to www.cmake.org|66.194.253.19|:80...
```

It is always retrying... Any thoughts?

Does anyone know what wrong I am doing here? Or is there any better way of installing latest version of cmake in my linux box?

```
userName@phx5qa01c-4e23:~/build$ uname -a
Linux phx5qa01c-4e23 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a firewall blocking your connection? Why using `wget`? Try to download that file (http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz) using a web browser.

Comment: Similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04 with a good answer.

Comment: I think your question is "How to install **latest cmake version** in Linux" but the command `sudo apt-get install cmake` does not install the latest version.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/952929/579410

Comment: The answers below didn't help me, but this answer to "Installing latest cmake on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS run via WSL: OpenSSL error" did: https://askubuntu.com/a/1205458/1191005

I also had to use this answer to "Unable to install libssl1.0.0:i386 due to unmet dependencies": https://askubuntu.com/a/1253788/1191005

Comment: follow this
https://apt.kitware.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Probably the server at www.cmake.org was just very busy. You could try again or download the file using your web browser.

There is however a much simpler way:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

**Update:** commenters point out that *"Ubuntu 12.04 is only shipping v2.8.7"* and *"14.04 is still shipping 2.8"*.  That is for a reason:  12.04 and 14.04 are **LTS releases** of Ubuntu.  LTS releases are intended to remain stable for 5 years, so they receive only security and critical updates, not the latest releases of packages.  Normal releases come out every 6 months, and are therefore more likely to come with a recent cmake.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 is only shipping v 2.8.7 of cmake with apt-get. The current release of version 2 is 2.8.12. I suggest you persevere with building it from source.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The latest version is almost never on apt.

Comment: 14.04  still shipping 2.8

Comment: @Stolas and other commenters: you are referring to **LTS Releases** of Ubuntu (12.04, 14.04). In an LTS release you only get security and critical fixes, and certainly not an upgrade of a package to its latest version. The whole point of LTS releases is that they don't do this, in order to guarantee stability for 5 years. I will update my answer to address this point.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The [StableReleaseUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) policy is *not* just for LTS releases. *All* Ubuntu releases, once actually released, only get fixes for security vulnerabilities or otherwise serious bugs. [As shown here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (and [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmake)), even non-LTS releases haven't received new `cmake` versions. [Separate backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) for some packages do exist (but not `cmake`).

Comment: @EliahKagan, how is the answer wrong? It does not claim that non-LTS releases receive package updates. (In fact, why would they when the next release is always less than 6 months away?) What I point out is that if you stick to an LTS release, you won't get `cmake` updates. When Stolas wrote "14.04 still shipping 2.8", Wily had been out for 5 months, carrying `cmake` 3.2. One month later, xenial came out with `cmake` 3.5. Zesty now has 3.7. Yet if Stolas is still on 14.04 LTS (which could be for another two years) they'll always get 2.8. Edited my answer to perhaps make this clearer.

Comment: This answer is wrong because `sudo apt-get install cmake` does not, by itself, ever upgrade `cmake` to a newer version. This does not work on any Ubuntu release. If your answer is actually "upgrade your Ubuntu system to a newer release" then you may want to edit again to make that clearer. (That would not be a reasonable solution for many users, though, and often there is no released version of Ubuntu whose repositories have the latest version of `cmake`.)

Comment: +1 @EliahKagan  **required != stable* and *stable != newer* and *newer != required**

Answer (score 447):

The most common situation is when you want to install the latest version of *cmake*, but your Operating System's repositories are not updated. For example, in my case I have a laptop running *Ubuntu 16.04*, and when I executed the command `sudo apt install cmake` the installed version was **3.5.1**; instead of **3.28.1** which is the current version at [cmake.org](https://www.cmake.org/download).

#### Teo, how can I get the latest version?

Well, we can install it by following one of these methods:

- **Using APT Repositories**
- **Building and Installing from source**
- **Using binary files**

#### A. Using APT Repositories (Recommended for normal users)

Kitware now provides an [APT Repository](https://apt.kitware.com/) that supports Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04. So we can install it easily following these steps:

**A-1.** Uninstall the default version provided by Ubuntu's package manager and configuration by using:

```sh
sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove cmake
```

or:

```sh
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

**A-2.** Prepare for installation

```sh
sudo apt update && \
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common lsb-release && \
sudo apt clean all
```

**A-3.** Obtain a copy of kitware's signing key.

```sh
wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg >/dev/null
```

**A-4.** Add kitware's repository to your sources list for Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04), Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04) and Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04).

```sh
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
```

**A-5.** As an optional step, is recommended that we also install the `kitware-archive-keyring` package to ensure that Kitware's keyring stays up to date as they rotate their keys.

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kitware-archive-keyring
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg
```

**A-5.Note** If running `sudo apt update` gets the following error:

```
Err:7 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6AF7F09730B3F0A4
Fetched 11.0 kB in 1s (7552 B/s)
```

Copy the public key `6AF7F09730B3F0A4` and run this command:

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF7F09730B3F0A4
```

**A-6.** Finally we can update and install the `cmake` package.

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cmake
```

#### B. Building and Installing (Recommended for developers)

For this approach you need to install the GCC tools:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libtool autoconf unzip wget
```

**B-1.** Uninstall the default version provided by Ubuntu's package manager as in **A-1**.

**B-2.** Go to the [official CMake webpage](https://www.cmake.org/download), then download and extract the latest version. Update the `version` and `build` variables in the following command to get the desired version:

```sh
version=3.28
build=1
## don't modify from here
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v$version/cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
tar -xzvf cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
cd cmake-$version.$build/
```

**B-3.** Install the extracted source by running:

```sh
./bootstrap
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

**B-4.** Test your new `cmake` version.

```sh
$ cmake --version
```

Results of `cmake --version`:

```sh
cmake version 3.28.X

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

#### C. Using binary files (`cmake-gui` might not work well)

**C-1.** Uninstall the default version provided by Ubuntu's package manager as in **A-1**.

**C-2.** Go to the [official CMake webpage](http://www.cmake.org/download), then download and install **the latest `.sh` version** in `opt/cmake`. Update the `version` and `build` variables in the following command to get the desired version:

```sh
version=3.28
build=1
## don't modify from here
limit=3.20
result=$(echo "$version >= $limit" | bc -l)
os=$([ "$result" == 1 ] && echo "linux" || echo "Linux")
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v$version/cmake-$version.$build-$os-x86_64.sh 
sudo mkdir /opt/cmake
sudo sh cmake-$version.$build-$os-x86_64.sh --prefix=/opt/cmake
```

**C-3.** Add the installed binary link to `/usr/local/bin/cmake` by running this:

```sh
sudo ln -s /opt/cmake/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake
```

**C-4.** Test your new `cmake` version as in **B-4**.

#### Note

In **3.28.X** the **X** represents the last part of the version that we defined as build. The build may change if **cmake** is updated. According to the official web page the [Latest Release is 3.28.1](https://cmake.org/download/#latest). If you want the [Previous Release 3.27.9](https://cmake.org/download/#previous) just replace the version and build parameters like this:

```sh
version=3.27
build=9
## don't modify from here
limit=3.20
result=$(echo "$version >= $limit" | bc -l)
os=$([ "$result" == 1 ] && echo "linux" || echo "Linux")
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v$version/cmake-$version.$build-$os-x86_64.sh 
sudo mkdir /opt/cmake
sudo sh cmake-$version.$build-$os-x86_64.sh --prefix=/opt/cmake
```

#### Observation

For previous versions of CMake (3.19.7 <=), remember that the file name contains an upper case `L` in `-Linux-x86_64.sh` and from version 3.20 it has a lower case `l` in `-linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: The make install command need root privileges.  The cmake --version command only works after open a new terminal because cmake is installed under /usr/local/bin/ by default, not /usr/bin/.

Comment: When I ran this, I got an error `CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!` and it failed to update `cmake`.

Comment: This is not a solution to UPDATE but to INSTALL cmake. Try this command or google it to find a solution: `sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data`

Comment: @Teocci I like your tutorial. Just a hint: For also getting `ccmake` (the CMake curses interface) built and installed you need to do `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev` first (see [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-January/053358.html), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270381/how-do-i-install-ncurses-header-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682956/ccmake-using-cmake-version-3-10)).

Comment: Note to also build the cmake-gui tool, add  --qt-gui to the bootstrap command.

Comment: `apt purge` includes `apt remove`, so it's pointless to do
`sudo apt remove cmake;
apt purge cmake`

Just do `apt purge`

Comment: Instruction set **A** produces: `bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory`. **B** works fine.

Comment: You might want to symlink all the `cmake` tools in `/bin` after the install, not just `cmake` itself. You can use `sudo cp -s /opt/cmake/bin/* /usr/local/bin` or `sudo cp -s /opt/cmake/cmake-$VERSION-Linux-x86_64/bin/* /usr/local/bin` to do that, depending on it you chose to install `cmake` in a versioned directory or not.

Comment: Pretty solid guide, and the one that actually work for me... The rest I found do not cover the process from start to end.

Comment: I tried B but `cmake --version` gives me `Command 'cmake' not found`

Comment: @Anakin If you get `bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory`, see HD189733b's upvoted comment above.

Comment: @Teocci Perhaps add a `. ~/.profile` or `. ~/.bashrc` step to **A-4** to fix this issue. Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: Why not use Kitware's APT repo for CMake which supports 16.04?

Comment: Kitware now release their source files and distributes them using Github, the links on their website have been updated to the format `https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v$version/cmake-$verison.$build-Linux-x86_64.sh`
But `wget` might not manage to download the file, so you will need to manually download it and run the rest of the commands as usual

Comment: My poor laptop just froze while executing `make` and I had to do a hard shutdown. Maybe it's better not to use all the cores? `-j$(($(nproc)-2))`?

Comment: For solution A, you may need to follow https://askubuntu.com/a/1390307/312805

Comment: `A` instructions working perfect `Ubuntu 22.04`, `cmake version 3.23.2`

Comment: @Teocci: Great. I have successfully installed using step A i.e. "Using APT Repositories (Recommended for normal users)".  However, can you please tell me how to reverse this step? I mean I want to remove the cmake installed through APT repository.

Comment: @BZKN just run `sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove cmake`

Comment: RE: Copyright and Content Licensing, read https://askubuntu.com/help/licensing - any publicly posted content here is auto-licensed under CC BY-SA of a specific version at the time of the post being made.  This is plastered **everywhere** in the SE network, with the Terms of Service and the help centers.  Everything is therefore under a CC BY-SA license.  This **permits** remixing, modification, etc. for any purpose - therefore any contributed edit *is* (I believe) legal under the TOS and if you want your stuff under a different license, don't post here on Ask Ubuntu / Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ThomasWard to whom u are talking to? to me? I didn't talk about copyright. First this post is under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license so u can Share and Adapt. What this means? simple you can share the link, use it in your company, adapt it by copying the content and put it in ur personal page, blog, copy part of it in ur own answer. But this is the original post. I will give u an example, everybody knows the Mona Lisa imagine it is under this license, can u go and paint over, put on her red lips or something like that? Of course not u can make a copy and change it

Comment: I had to `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/bin/cmake` to make it work

Comment: Can confirm this steps still works in 2024. Able to update WSL cmake to version 3.28.3.

Answer (score 96):

Kitware now has an APT repository that currently supports 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

All repos support AMD64, ARM32, ARM64 architectures and 18.04 also supports x86

**Install Instructions:**

1. Remove old version of cmake

   ```
    sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
   ```
2. Obtain a copy of the signing key

   ```
    wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg >/dev/null
   ```
3. Add the repository to your sources list

   a. For Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish (22.04)

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ jammy main'
   ```

   b. For Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04)

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal main'
   ```

   c. For Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04)

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'
   ```
4. Update and install

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install cmake
   ```

Comment: Best solution as of today but the repository does not support the arm64 architecture.

Comment: Related links: https://cmake.org/download/ https://apt.kitware.com/

Comment: unsecure repo error

W: GPG error: https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 291F9FF6FD385783
E: The repository 'https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


Better use the PIP approach below

Comment: is the first step necessary? It should upgrade anyway right?

Comment: @Bizmate [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943539/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai) should help

Comment: For me it worked only with `python3.6`, but not with `python3.11` and `python.3.9`.

Answer (score 60):

I love the following way because you can get a recent version without much trouble.

Kitware seems to officially support a pip wheels release. So you can get latest cmake just by doing:

> pip install --upgrade cmake

Here is the blog about it:
https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-python-wheels/

Comment: Definitely the most useful answer! I wish I thought of that a year ago. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably the easiest one of all!

Comment: Thank you! This is much easier than alternatives.

Comment: Happy to hear people find it useful. IMO it is the easiest and most reliable way. And it is also officially supported

Comment: Thanks. Your steps as written exactly didn't work for me, but some minor adjustments and they did: On 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa), I first had to install pip using `apt-get install -y python3-pip`. Then I could install Cmake using `pip3 install --upgrade cmake`

Comment: this doesn't install cmake-gui unfortunately\

Comment: This worked for me but only after opening a new terminal

Answer (score 54):

First [uninstall any cmake package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software) previously installed. Then:

1. Go to http://www.cmake.org/download/ and download the latest .sh installer
2. Install it (for example) in `opt/cmake` by running

   ```
   sudo mkdir /opt/cmake
   sudo sh <installer filename> --prefix=/opt/cmake
   ```
3. Add the cmake **bin** directory to your path: https://askubuntu.com/a/170240/359343

Installed in this way, `cmake-gui` looks a little bit horrible, if you find a way to fix it please feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: Add a link from /usr/local/bin/cmake to the installed binary. This way there is no need to change the PATH.
    `sudo ln -s /opt/cmake/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake`

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: really, this is most useful answer for initial question

Comment: This gives me broken cmake-gui, which doesn't work over xRDP (prev version worked), and xRDP is the only way to access the server.

Comment: @stiv 1. Did you verify `cmake` after the installation is working, and that you have no other `cmake` version in your path? 2. Can you verify if you are using the cmake-gui provided in the installation, and not some older version? (To know the version, append `--version` to the command line)

Comment: I would definitely suggest this answer to anyone coming around looking for a prebuilt version of x86-64 CMake

Comment: `for i in /opt/cmake/cmake-3.19.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/*; do sudo ln -s "$i" /usr/local/bin/"$i"; done` makes all the symbolic links, and may fix the noted-above cmake-gui issue.

Comment: This also works on wsl btw

Comment: A release and a feature worth circumventing apt are 2 different things. I just downloaded `cmake` yesterday via apt, and it has all the usual features. If you are worried about using an up-to-date make, you should be using `autotools` on Debian anyway. I spend a significant amount of my time on here telling people NOT to do exactly what your answer suggests. When you install like this, `dpkg` doesn't even know this package exists. If you are going to do it the axe backward way, at least port to a `.deb` package, or better yet get a real one that was configured by a maintainer, and load it...

Comment: ...into `dpkg` manually with `dpkg -i`. The first time you go to download a pkg that requires `cmake` as a dependency, what will you do then? Your `cmake` won't fill that dependency. This is only one of many such issues that can be avoided by making sure that your system's software is properly managed.  Ubuntu is a well oiled machine. It will run forever so long as you keep the oil filled. Apologies if this sounds harsh, but this is not something you should do unless you absolutely need a feature that is not available via `apt` / `snap`.

Comment: @NateT The question is about "how do you get the latest version of cmake" (i.e. with all the latest features), and this is the answer. If you have a better answer please draft it and publish it.

Comment: Yea, that's why I didn't DV any answers (the UV was me.) In that context, just because he is in a VM and redos are easy, its not a big deal. The reason for the comments is because most of the users who will need this resource in the future (those new to linux environments) wont know the difference. Put yourself in a new user's shoes and imagine the impression you would get if you landed here. Gonna delete a few comments. Starting to look like graffiti : )

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me! For step 2, type y for the license and N for adding the additional path folder.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. A suggestion might be that you could edit `PATH` environment variable by appending `export PATH="${PATH}:/opt/cmake/bin"` to `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 39):

Just in case if someone need to install latest CMAKE in a docker image (like me..). In this case is 3.7.2, but you can check here https://cmake.org/download/ as already pointed out

```
#install latest cmake
ADD https://cmake.org/files/v3.7/cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.sh /cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN mkdir /opt/cmake
RUN sh /cmake-3.7.2-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/opt/cmake --skip-license
RUN ln -s /opt/cmake/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake
RUN cmake --version
```

Comment: Nice, undocumented --skip-license option :)

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat, `--help` shows this option and there is no other documentation.

Comment: @vulcanraven It was added to `--help` in v.3.10.0 on 2018-12-01. This answer and my comment refer to v.3.7.2.

Answer (score 6):

For a Docker container, best run

```
RUN wget -qO- "https://cmake.org/files/v3.12/cmake-3.12.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz" | \
  tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C /usr/local
```

Adjust the version, if needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can find very recent versions of cmake through snap. For example, as of writing this answer, the latest version of cmake is 3.15.3, and snap has version 3.15.2.

```
sudo apt-get purge cmake
sudo snap install cmake --classic
```

Comment: Assuming a bash terminal, you might need `hash -r` afterwards to ensure the updated cmake binary is found.

Comment: @hertzsprung that is important, without hash -r, I cannot run cmake binary on terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You can also execute the following:

```
export fn=/tmp/cmake.sh && ls $fn && (echo "use previous $fn? Enter for yes, ctrl+d for no." && read) || (wget -O $fn http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.0/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-i386.sh 1>&2) && (cd /opt && sudo bash ${fn} && echo sudo ln -f -s /opt/cmake*/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake && cd -)
```

This script

- fetches make 3.0.2
  ** if it was already downloaded in this session, then you might reuse it if you did not finish the installation
- then it <strike>copies</strike> *makes link* to the bin `cmake`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove old version using:

```
apt-get purge cmake
```

Download binary version of `cmake` archived in a tarball. You can use new version of `cmake` by adding its `bin` directory path to `$PATH`. An alternative solution is to extract `tar.gz` package and go to the directory made after extracting and run following commands:

```
cp -r bin /usr/
cp -r doc /usr/share/
cp -r man /usr/share/
cp -r share /usr/
```

The second method is the same as installation process which `.deb` package does!

Answer (score 2):

[qwr](https://askubuntu.com/users/477026/qwr)'s answer to use snap can be good but if you want something even newer, cmake makes building a DEB from source easy. The following assumes you have a recent cmake already installed. Ubuntu 18.04's apt install cmake will definitely work here.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep cmake
git clone http://www.cmake.org/cmake.git
cd cmake
git tag
# find the highest tagged release value (hint, rarely at the bottom)
git co tags/<highest tagged release value>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
cpack -G DEB
# you built a single deb that has what Ubuntu provides as two debs, the binary
# deb and the additional architecture independent data files
sudo apt remove cmake-data
sudo dpkg -i cmake-<highest tagged release value>-Linux-x86_64.deb
```

Comment: Now run the command `man cmake` and you will see one more reason that apt outshines the install from source method 99.999 % of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of cmake from backports, where many latest versions reside. The particular backports depends on your current OS version. For example, running Debian Stretch, add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

Then install from this backport, aka:

```
sudo apt-get -t stretch-backports install -y cmake
```