# How to install cmake 3.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cmake

Default cmake version of 14.04 is 2.8. How can I install cmake 3.2 and replace the default one? Or how can I upgrade 2.8 to 3.2?

Comment: Be aware that some system-installed packages will not work correctly with cmake 3.2 on 14.04. For example Eigen installs its CMake modules in /usr/share/cmake-2.8, where they obviously can't be found by CMake 3.2.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Either use a PPA or compile it yourself:

1. Installation by a PPA (Upgrade to 3.2)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   - When cmake is not yet installed:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install cmake
     ```
   - When cmake is already installed:

     ```
     sudo apt-get upgrade
     ```
2. Compile it yourself

   Currently, the latest version is 3.2.2, the following instructions based on this version. You should therefore check [this URL](http://www.cmake.org/download/) and adjust the file name accordingly.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
   tar xf cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
   cd cmake-3.2.2
   ./configure
   make
   ```

   Now you can have to choose an installation type to decide, I recommend installing with `checkinstall`, as this creates a DEB package.

   - With `checkinstall`

     ```
     sudo apt-get install checkinstall
     sudo checkinstall
     ```
   - With `make install`

     ```
     sudo make install
     ```

Comment: The first method doesn't work for me. I run both install or upgrade and both are no-op for me.  Install from source works, and I like the approach to install as .deb package.

Comment: Yeah, the first method doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Method 1 doesn't work and I had to purge the cmake package to get back to a working cmake (2.8) by reinstalling. Method 2 works fine.

Comment: Method 1 did not initially work for me (it installed, but cmake did not work correctly due to things like CMAKE_ROOT not being found), but after purging the cmake package (as well as cmake-data just in case) and then reinstalling 3.2 through apt-get it worked fine.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't have `add-apt-repository` (I didn't, assumedly because I was installing on a slimmed-down VM), you need to install the `software-properties-common` package.

Comment: @JAB which package you had to purge? ,`cmake`?

Comment: @JAB thank you for the comment. I've added the command to install `software-properties-common`

Comment: @A.B. I purged both `cmake` and `cmake-data`; I didn't experiment individually to see if only one actually needed to be purged. I had a similar issue on another Ubuntu distro where I manually installed CMake 3.3.1 in /usr/local; I assumed both the package installation and manual installation could exist simultaneously, but doing so left the CMake configuration in an inconsistent state and I had to purge the package install. It may have had something to do with paths determined by some configuration file somewhere that the cmake executable checks, but I didn't feel like digging deeply into it.

Comment: apt-get upgrade did not work for me; 
apt-get remove cmake, apt-get install cmake did

Comment: For the first method, run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install cmake 3.x. Otherwise, the cmake package will be held back and only cmake-data will be installed.

Comment: Just a side-note for anyone who is building OpenCV 3 from source and has a problem with `cmake` not finding the Python libraries for 2.7 and/or 3.0 even though the `dev` packages are installed - this fixes the issue!

Comment: For step 2, where should I be doing this?  /user/home/ or /usr/src/ or what?  If either, which is better?  Thanks for your very clear answer.

Comment: Copy-pasted `sudo apt-get upgrade`  ( `cmake` absent) and got all my other packages upgraded, except `cmake`...

Comment: PPA did not work.

Comment: I was having to do the purge method as others indicated, I was going to use this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615451/cmake-missing-modules-directory, but it was going to have me uninstall a lot of packages I need. #2 works.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04, simply `sudo apt-get install cmake` works well !

Comment: If you are getting `CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!`, uninstall then reinstall `cmake` and `cmake-data`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615451/cmake-missing-modules-directory

Comment: This only works if I use `apt-get install cmake3` (note the 3 at the end).

Comment: Linux raised a security error on first method

Comment: And the authenticity of this PPA repository? "george-edison55"?

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic It's like any foreign repository you use. Either you trust or you don't.

Answer (score 39):

There are three options:

- install from a PPA
- install the pre-built binary distribution from cmake.org
- compile it yourself

### Installation from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt-get update
```

When cmake is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

When cmake is already installed:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### Installation from cmake.org binary distrubtion

```
curl -sSL https://cmake.org/files/v3.5/cmake-3.5.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz | sudo tar -xzC /opt
```

CMake executables will be in `/opt/cmake-3.5.2-Linux-x86_64/bin/`.

### Compile it yourself

Currently, the latest version is 3.5.2, the following instructions based on this version. You should therefore check [the download page](https://cmake.org/download/) and adjust the file name accordingly.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.5/cmake-3.5.2.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.5.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.5.2
./configure
make
```

Now you can have to choose an installation type to decide, I recommend installing with `checkinstall`, as this creates a DEB package.

- with `checkinstall`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```
- with `make install`

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

Comment: It adds a "Installation from cmake.org binary distrubtion" option. Also improves the formatting and bumps the cmake download URL to the newest release. I tried to just edit the accepted answer but my edits where not accepted by the author.

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure if I am late to the party, but recently on Ubuntu 14.04 I faced same issues and this is how I got it solved. First, you need to remove the existing `cmake` by executing the command:

`sudo apt-get remove cmake`

Hit <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>. Next, you need to install `cmake3` by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get upgrade 

sudo apt-get install cmake3
```

Assuming, my answer will get old in few years, consider searching for a cmake package that has a number associated with it. For example, at this time, cmake3 works for me.

To do so, all you have to execute is

`apt-cache search cmake`

Once you find the package, just install as suggested.

Thank you 
Happy Coding!

Comment: Yeah, simply `sudo apt-get install cmake` works well.

Comment: @EricWang Yea Eric, now with Ubuntu 16.04 and above it works fine.

Comment: This must be an accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

Try to build it from source, install it and adjust your $PATH variables to make it available. Maybe you should add the exported variables to your bashrc. That is basically how I would do it, please change file and folder names to your needs:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget http://url.to/cmake-3.2-src.tar.gz
tar xzf cmake-3.2-src.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.2-src
./configure
make
# If make finishes without errors:
sudo make install
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cmake --version # This should give v3.2
```

Comment: The URL does not work.

Comment: An working URL will not point to newer versions in the future, please check cmake's website for the most recent version.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS simply run:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install the latest from the sh from https://cmake.org/download/

```
cd /usr
sudo wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -P /usr/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/cmake-3.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo ./cmake-3.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
sudo snap install cmake --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, all I needed was:

```sh
apt-get -y install cmake
```

I found that info [here](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first-step/installation.html).