# How to install cmake,ccmake from source?

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I followed the first answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04) question.

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
 wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.5.0-rc2.tar.gz
 tar xf cmake-3.5.0-rc2.tar.gz
 cd cmake-3.5.0-rc2
 ./configure
 make
 sudo apt-get install checkinstall
 sudo checkinstall
```

And this worked but ccmake was not installed. While googling I couldn't find how to add to the build/install cmake-curses-gui too.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110169/update-ccmake-on-ubuntu-when-building-from-source

1. Install libncurses5-dev
2. Reconfigure/compile/install cmake
3. Restart the shell (initially it was available, but the shell couldn't find it)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution (2018-12-07):

This doesn't work out of the box for me on Ubuntu 18.04 but the `libncurses5-dev` is a prerequisite library.

As said on SO [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110169/update-ccmake-on-ubuntu-when-building-from-source); I fixed it by running `cmake-gui` (the one previously installed without ccmake) in the sources directory of cmake itself (sounds strange but worked like a charm).

Then, I looked for `BUILD_CursesDialog` (as suggested in this thread [[1]](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-November/047657.html)) in cmake-gui.
This option wasn't checked, so I checked it.
Click `configure` & `generate`.
Close `cmake-gui`.
Then run `make -j4` & `$ sudo checkinstall` (I previously used `$ sudo dpkg -r cmake` to properly remove cmake).

[1] https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-November/047657.html

#### Checks:

```
$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

$ which cmake-gui
/usr/local/bin/cmake-gui

$ which ccmake
/usr/local/bin/ccmake

$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.20181205-gf92e9

$ cmake-gui --version
ccmake-gui version 3.13.20181205-gf92e9

$ ccmake --version
ccmake version 3.13.20181205-gf92e9
```

Answer (score 0):

cmake's bootstrap script generates a Makefile that will also build ccmake if (as s.k. points out) the boolean variable BUILD_CursesDialog is set.

To decide the truth value of BUILD_CursesDialog, the bootstrap script tries compiling a simple ncurses program. If the compilation of the ncurses program fails, the BUILD_CursesDialog variable is unset. If libncurses5-dev is installed, the ncurses program builds and thus, the Makefile generated for cmake upon bootstrap also has instructions to build ccmake.

With this understanding of the current build process, the sequence of steps listed by augre are to be followed. Additionally, remember to also clean any temporary build files first (coming from a similar experience, I believe this is what s.k. did not do, and found an admirable :) hack to work around).

Thus, for me, running off git, the process is:

- git clean -f -d

Replicate augre's solution:

- install libncurses5-dev
- Reconfigure/compile/install cmake
- Potentially restart terminal