# How to compile cmake locally

Tags: compiling, cmake

I've seen [tutorials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to compile cmake globally. However I don't want to endanger my current system configuration. I only need a higher version of cmake to compile libgpuarray for theano, but I don't want to overwriten my existing cmake configuration.

Does anyone know how to do that?
Can I specify a local path when calling `./configure` ? 
By the way: How can I look up options that are available for the `./configure` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, `./configure` scripts provide a `--prefix` option fo this. So for example

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

or

```
./configure --prefix=/opt
```

(for much software, `/usr/local` is the default).

You can usually run `./configure --help` to see this and other options that may affect the installation path e.g.

```
$ ./configure --help | grep install
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
By default, `make install' will install all the files in
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
```