# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Tags: 16.04, apt, gnupg

When I run `apt-get update`, I get this error message:

```
Err:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
```

I understand what causes this issue. I wonder how to fix it.

**EDIT:**

I tried the most upvoted solution provided in the duplicate link:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
```

I got this new issue which does not seem to be resolved on this website according to the posts I saw:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.jyolnTyZuJ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
6494C6D6997C215E
gpg: requesting key 997C215E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Comment: It works for me. You have some internet connection problem.

Comment: @Fabby: To me it reads almost exactly the same as the first alternative of [karthick87’s](/a/15272/175814).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Bowing to the master! **:-)** Urgh... Cannot retract reopen vote!  **;-(**

Comment: That error can also be caused by putting an ASCII-Armored file in `/usr/share/keyrings`, if you are doing that to avoid using `apt-key add` as recommended here: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty

Answer (score 186, accepted):

I want to share what I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75892/keyserver-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-a-gpg-public-key) (running over port **80**):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
```

And that was successful:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.BX24beQ8ze/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv-keys
6494C6D6997C215E
gpg: requesting key 997C215E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key D38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" 3 new signatures
gpg: key D38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" 1 new subkey
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:            new subkeys: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 3
```

I then run `sudo apt-get update` and everything went fine.

Comment: It looks like your default settings are non-standard. It works for me without specification of a port.

Comment: @Pilot6 or they're behind a firewall of some sort, so port 11371 is blocked.

Comment: It works for me without the scheme and port.

Comment: This post https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldn-t-be-verified helped me before I could find this one.

Comment: Doesn't want to import that key it says it already exists.