# Cannot add ppa:graphics-drivers

Tags: nvidia, updates, ppa

I tried to execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
to install the latest GTX 1070 driver as explained [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2017/06/11/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-10-17-04/)

This command ended up with an error:

> Get:12 http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease [23.2 kB]
>   Err:12 http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease
>
> The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 696DBE66A72D76DA Fetched 23.2 kB in 3s (8,640
>   B/s)
>
> Reading package lists... Done W: An error occurred during the
>   signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous
>   index files will be used. GPG error:
>   http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 696DBE66A72D76DA W: Failed to fetch
>   http://packages.blackfire.io/debian/dists/any/InRelease  The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 696DBE66A72D76DA W: Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Then I added the PUBKEY with

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 696DBE66A72D76DA

as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/943548/247771).

Now I get this error:

> Get:12 http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease [23.2 kB]
>
> Reading package lists... Done      E: Repository
>   'http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease' changed its
>   'Origin' value from 'packagecloud.io/sensiolabs/sensiolabs' to
>   'packagecloud.io/blackfire-io/stable' E: Repository
>   'http://packages.blackfire.io/debian any InRelease' changed its
>   'Label' value from 'sensiolabs' to 'stable' N: This must be accepted
>   explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for details.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you're mixing up event/cause.  I can't see the connection between the PPA & your errors, and suspect they are unrelated.  Your errors are I believe due to your sources, and the PPA only caused the error to be noticed (it was the `sudo apt update` run at end of PPA add that made you notice your issue)