# Is there a good PPA for cmake backports?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ppa, pip, cmake

I am looking for a reliable PPA for cmake backports.

I need it for both Xenial and Trusty (travis-ci). Ideally I would like to have at least cmake 3.8.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know I was asking for a PPA but in general terms any reliable deployment of cmake for 14.04/16.04 is good. Kitware's blog shows an answer:

https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-python-wheels/

They seem to officially support a pip wheels release. So you can get latest cmake just by doing:

`pip install --upgrade cmake`

In addition, if you are using virtualenv or conda, you can have different cmake versions at the same time.

***Update:*** the pip package may show a low version number. At the moment, it is 0.8, however, it does install cmake 3.9

Comment: it was about to install cmake-0.8.0

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand you comment

Comment: I did `pip install --upgrade cmake` but I got this: `Downloading cmake-0.8.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.2MB)
    1% |▋                               | 337kB` thx

Comment: yes, the version 0.8.0 refers to the pip package version. The cmake version that it installs is 3.9 (check here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmake/)

Comment: I see. My mistake, but it *is* confusing! thx a lot

Answer (score 26):

There is now an official CMake APT repository, hosted by Kitware ([announcement](https://blog.kitware.com/ubuntu-cmake-repository-now-available/)), which has the latest CMake version. Currently, Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and 18.04 (Bionic) are supported, but not Trusty. Instructions to set it up can be found at https://apt.kitware.com/ . I've reproduced key details here:

> ...
>
> 2. Obtain a copy of our signing key:
>
>    ```
>    wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | sudo apt-key add -
>    ```
> 3. Add the repository to your sources list and update.
>
>    For Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04):
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'
>    sudo apt-get update
>    ```
>
>    For Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04):
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ xenial main' 
>    sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 4. As an optional step, we recommend that you also install our `kitware-archive-keyring` package to ensure that your keyring stays up
>      to date as we rotate our keys. Do the following:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install kitware-archive-keyring
>    sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg del C1F34CDD40CD72DA
>    ```

After this, `sudo apt-get install cmake` will install the latest CMake.

Comment: Excellent - thank you for this info. As of July 2019, this repo supplied cmake 3.14.5 for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This repository doesn't support the arm64 architecture.

Comment: This also supports 20.04 LTS (focal)

Comment: To build and install arm64 / aarch64 .deb packages from Kitware git repository (tested on Jetson Nano with Ubuntu 18.04 and should work for later Ubuntu versions too): `cd /tmp/ && git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/debian/cmake.git && cd cmake && perl -pi -e 's|(verify-build-flags:)|$1\n\t\$(call \$(flag_action),BUILD_TESTING,OFF,"Skip tests")|' ./debian/rules && sudo mk-build-deps -irt 'apt -y' && dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc && sudo apt -y install ../cmake*.deb` (perl here is used to turn off tests because they take a long time and they add nothing to the binary package).

Comment: Where can we find the package index?
I'd like to check which version of CMake is proposed for each OS.  I went into bugs when using CMake 3.27 with pybind

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be no reliable PPA with *the most modern version* of `cmake` in place but if you are happy with using prebuilt binaries from the `cmake` download page the following should help (for 64bit Ubuntu):

```
cd $HOME
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.12/cmake-3.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo sh cmake-3.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/usr/local --exclude-subdir
```

This is *not* integrated with the Ubuntu package management system but installs neatly to `/usr/local` and on my system then demonstrates the following:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ cmake --version | head -n1
cmake version 3.12.0
```

Subsequent removal is simply a matter of running the following *single command* in a Terminal window:

```
sudo rm -rfv /usr/local/bin/{cmake,cpack,ccmake,cmake-gui,ctest} \
             /usr/local/doc/cmake \
             /usr/local/man/man1/{ccmake.1,cmake.1,cmake-gui.1,cpack.1,ctest.1} \
             /usr/local/man/man7/cmake-* \
             /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12
```

This leaves your system *clean* and perhaps ready to install *an even more modern version* :).

**References:**

- [cmake: Get the Software](https://cmake.org/download/) The official download page for cmake. Some extra information concerning the .sh installer files.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a ppa for ubuntu to use in travis-ci. I could build things myself for a local computer but I would like to avoid that in a CI server. Still, I got the answer I was looking: No reliable PPA available...

Comment: There are a few more files to remove. Find them using `find /usr/local -name '*cmake*' -o -name '*cpack*' -o -name '*ctest*'`.