# Avogadro 1.2.0 installation

Tags: software-installation, zlib

I get this error message:

```
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:124 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:243 (find_package)
```

Comment: Could you post the exact command you used to get this message and try to format your question to 'code' (select the relevant part, and press the `{}` button?

Comment: Also please post your Ubuntu release version. Apparently Avogrado software needs a newer `cmake` version so you may need to do this https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/692175

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, and it is on the installation instructions of avogadro that 3rd step "cmake ../ " command that results to this error