# After upgrading the cmake, I am still getting error for installing the ITK?

Tags: 14.04, cmake, makefile

I want to install a software, which requires ITK and it is raising an error:

```
[ 52%] Performing configure step for 'ITKv5'
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.10.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMakeFiles/ITKv5.dir/build.make:107: recipe for target 'ITKv5-prefix/src/ITKv5-stamp/ITKv5-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [ITKv5-prefix/src/ITKv5-stamp/ITKv5-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ITKv5.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ITKv5.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I removed the current cmake (3.5.1) and installed it again from cmake website and by following the [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). The newest version is `cmake version 3.11.3` , However, I still get the same error. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: If you get the same error `CMake 3.10.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1` you did not uninstall the old CMake. Which one of the many answers present there did you follow exactly?

Comment: @dadexix86 I uninstalled with these commands `sudo apt remove cmake`
  and `sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake`

Comment: Does the software really require ITKv5? You can get `itk3-dev` direct from the Ubuntu repository

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu `itk3` : OOP extension for Tk - run-time files. .... "**ITK-5.0**" : The Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit >> ITK, medical image analysis, Medical Visualization, Performance https://itk.org/ → → https://blog.kitware.com/itk-5-0-alpha-2-performance/

Comment: Which answer did you follow from the instructions you have linked?  I did the cmake install from https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/231142 and it worked fine.  You need to remember that after you install it you need to kill the terminal you are in and open a new one for the path to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu 14.04 - amd64**. ... Build a cmake for **ITK5.0**, e.g. `cmake_3.10.3` : Get the "build-deps" → `$ sudo apt install g++ libncurses5-dev gfortran libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-sphinx libjsoncpp0 libarchive-dev libexpat1-dev libuv-dev librhash-dev liblzma-dev emacs python-all-dev desktop-file-utils libx11-dev libjsoncpp-dev`

Result : `cmake_3.10.3-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nUI2nRc7KfbxJZuQb9XduCiLt_qpZxlR/view?usp=sharing

Install / update 'cmake' : `$ sudo gdebi Downloads/cmake_3.10.3-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb`

---

`$ cd ITK-5.0a02/build/ && cmake .. && make` : The 259 executable´s are created → 1.2GB (Build time = 3 .. 4 hours)

`$ sudo make install > ITK5_install.log` → https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip7zbyzifgqlkzm/ITK5_install.log.txt?dl=0 → Line 2904: `/usr/local/bin/itkTestDriver`

Comment: Knud Larson Thank you for your help, but I get the following error once I am trying to install `$ sudo gdebi cmake_3.10.3-1ubuntu14_amd64.deb `
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Breaks existing package 'cmake-curses-gui' dependency cmake (= 3.5.1-1ubuntu3)

Comment: Simple : Remove all "cmake" packages version 3.5.1 → `sudo apt remove cmake*`. ....  List installed : `ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep cmake`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much for your patience to help me. This worked very well.