# Cmake has not updated, what I am doing wrong?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, cmake

I uninstalled cmake by the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove cmake
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

and then installed the new version from cmake website. 
When I ran `cmake --version` I am getting the version that I have installed:

```
cmake version 3.11.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

However, when again I am trying to run this command, it seems it still has the previous version

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cmake is already the newest version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

I ran the following commands:

```
~$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
~$ apt-cache policy cmake
cmake:
  Installed: 3.5.1-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.5.1-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.5.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Could you please guide me? I cannot install a software that needs higher version of cmake.

Comment: Please add output of  `which cmake` and `apt-cache policy cmake` to the question.

Comment: Installing a new version manually has nothing to do with `apt` : The "Package data base" has no information about manual installs, only knows about [packages.deb]. .... Your previous question 2 days ago about the same → https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045044/after-upgrading-the-cmake-i-am-still-getting-error-for-installing-the-itk#comment1704137_1045044

Comment: @N0rbert I updated the question

Comment: The tags say 12.04, 14.04, apt-cache's output indicates 16.04. Is this Schrodinger's Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru sorry I am not expert and do not know what do you mean about `Schrodinger's Ubuntu` ? If you mean about ubuntu version, it is ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed from official website.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for your comment, however, i could not resolve my issue.

Comment: @S.EB : Please read my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045044/after-upgrading-the-cmake-i-am-still-getting-error-for-installing-the-itk#comment1704137_1045044

Comment: `cmake` is located in */usr/local/bin/cmake* and that is the problem. Remove it with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake` and try again.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for your patience and help

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you very much for your help and patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `which cmake` says that your `cmake` is located in */usr/local/bin/cmake* and that is the problem.

Remove it with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake` and try again.

Comment: Why does it need to be removed? Shouldn't `apt` just update CMake? I also ran `which cmake` then ran `sudo rm` on the result, then `sudo apt-get install cmake` and got `cmake is already the newest version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.` which I find very strange! This was fixed with `sudo apt remove cmake
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake` but `sudo apt-get install cmake` still installed `3.5.1-1ubuntu3` which is certainly not the most recent version!