# Can't install Window AppMenu Applet

Tags: bash, kubuntu

I am new to Linux and I've been trying to install the plasma widgets [window Appmenu](https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-appmenu) and [window buttons](https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-buttons). They show up in the widget list but without a icon and cannot be used.

When I run `sh install.sh` in the directory where I extracted the files, I got the following:

```
install.sh: 1: [: -a: unexpected operator
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
install.sh: 5: install.sh: cmake: not found
make: No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Then it asks for the password and I get:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.`

Can I get a straightforward guide on how to install correctly?

Comment: What is the source for "the plasma widgets window Appmenu & window buttons"? Please post the link.

Comment: https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-buttons , https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-appmenu

Comment: What is your version of Kubuntu? And what does `plasmashell --version` show?

Comment: kubuntu 18.04, 5.12.8

Comment: There's mention of certain "development packages" that are needed. Do you have those? I don't use widgets which aren't already there by default and so can't help. Maybe you could ask at https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/ where I know the developer is available.

Answer (score 1):

**The `cmake` command is needed to build that code, and you don't have it.** This, rather than the `[: -a: unexpected operator` message, appears to be what is actually keeping your build from continuing. So first install `cmake`. Some software needs a very new version of `cmake` to build ([which you can install](https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/22949) if you need to) but most does not. I recommend you install the `cmake` package.

While you're at it, it's a good idea to make sure you have the usual toolchain for building programs on your Ubuntu system, too, which the `build-essential` package will get you.

These commands will install both `cmake` and those other tools:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential cmake
```

This will likely be sufficient to enable you to successfully build the software, or at least to get past the current error you're facing. However, I recommend you delete the `build` directory and its contents before proceeding:

```
rm -r build
```

After further troubleshooting steps that involve installing or removing software or editing files from the source code (or, if you like, even every time you build the source code), I recommend removing the build directory and starting fresh.

The messages you're getting about `-a` are probably not stopping the build from succeeding. You can probably ignore them. They also would likely go away if you used `bash` instead of `sh`, though I don't think that's the best solution. If you want to get rid of them or you suspect they are causing a problem then you can either edit the `install.sh` script to use the appropriate test (or no test) or you can manually perform the actions that script performs. So if you want to do something about this, see below for the details.

---

In the source code for both [applet-window-buttons](https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-buttons/blob/master/install.sh) and [applet-window-appmenu](https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-appmenu/blob/master/install.sh), `install.sh` currently has this as its complete contents:

```bash
if ! [ -a build ] ; then
    mkdir build
fi
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .. -Wnodev
make
sudo make install
```

This is the file you are attempting to run with `sh` that is producing errors. **Its use of the `-a` test is very strange.** `-a` typically appears between two other expressions, and causes `[` to return true when both expressions are true.

In Ubuntu, `sh` is provided by `dash`. If you use `bash` instead of `dash`, it may work (or appear to work). Perhaps that's what the authors did. However, instead of doing that, I recommend you either fix the script or just manually do what it does.

If you want to fix the script, **one way would be to replace `-a` with `-e` or `-d`**. The `-e` test takes a filename operand and checks if it exists; `-d` checks if it exists and is a directory. Another way to fix the script would just be to remove the `if` and `fi` lines entirely; `mkdir` would fail if the directory exists, but that's no problem.

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .. -Wnodev
make
sudo make install
```

But all this script does is create a `build` directory if there isn't one, change into it with `cd`, run `cmake` with some arguments, run `make`, and then run `sudo make install`. **You can just do these things yourself.** One way to do so is to run those commands in your interactive shell, one after another.

This has advantages. As written, the script doesn't stop just because some step reports failure, but you probably would want to stop. You could make further modifications to the script to achieve that (perhaps ending each line except the first and last with `&&`) but it's probably easier to just run the commands yourself if you're not planning on compiling the code numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing some issues. Managed to build it on Kubuntu 21.04.
Following should be kept in mind

- Delete the build/ folder in subsequent build attempts
- Install the dependencies. [This](https://github.com/psifidotos/applet-window-appmenu/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md) can be referred.
- Do make sure gcc, cmake etc. are not conflicting
- After the install, the widget appears in the "add widget" option on panel