# CLion won't track compiler via WSL

Tags: compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake, clion

downloaded compiler and everything. Tho for some reason it downloads only cmake 3.10 and I need 3.15. I updated it following this guide [How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line/355574) but my clion just wont use the cmake 3.15

Screenshot of terminal and CLion settings:

[image]

I am quite begginer to this. I used to code in C, but I had to learn C++ in which I need newer version of cmake.
Thank you very much for every advice.

Comment: Use `which cmake` to determine where cmake 3.10 is installed. CLion looks for cmake in a fixed path. You can create a symbolic link to point to your cmake 3.15

Comment: Why you need cmake to learn C++? Learning a programing language does not depend on the build system.

Comment: the compiler need it, dunno why.