# Installing latest cmake on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS run via WSL: OpenSSL error

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssl, cmake

Using CLion on Windows (a C++ IDE), I'd like to install the latest version of cmake on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS run via WSL (the current version of CLion requires cmake > 3.15, while I have only version 3.10.2 installed).

Following cmake installation instructions found in [a related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/707749), an error occurs when bootstrapping CMake (first step in A-3 in linked answer):

```
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found version "1.1.1")
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:454 (message):
Could not find OpenSSL.  Install an OpenSSL development package or
configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have already installed `libssl-dev` as recommended in [another cmake-related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27551158/2918960).

Any ideas on how this issue can be fixed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same problem last year. My solution was this:

run the following in your WSL terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg software-properties-common wget
```

After that is finished

```
wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | sudo apt-key add -
```

Next add the updated repository by typing in the following

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

And it should be updated to the latest version.

**Note: if the above doesn't work, be very careful when trying the below steps. It is not elegant, it is not clean, but it does work.**

If this does not work. Go to https://cmake.org/download/ and download the Latest Ubuntu version. If you have a folder where you maintain all your projects I suggest downloading the file into your top most directory where your projects are.

For example all my projects are in a folder called "Github" so I would download the file into my "Github" Folder. If there is not a top level directory create a cmake folder in the C drive or what ever drive you save your projects to.

Next after its finished downloading Extract the file (through winrar/winzip/7zip/ or terminal) into that same directory. Once extracted `cd` into the folder (cmake-{version number}) and do the following commands.

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

This will make the latest version of cmake and then install the required components. It can take a while to have everything build and installed.

Once that is done you are going to want to locate the /bin/ folder inside your cmake folder. Make sure a file called "cmake" is in this folder. Copy the path of this directory and type the following

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

You can use vi or vim or whatever text editor you want from within the terminal.
At the end of the file type the following

```
alias cmake="{PATH to /bin/ folder}/cmake"
```

Make sure if you copied the path from windows explorer you replace \ with /
save the file and exit.

Restart your terminal and type

```
cmake --version
```

It should show up with whichever version you just downloaded.

Congrats you now have the updated version of cmake.

As per the comment by John, this is version specific, these exact same directions (for the first method at least) are available [here](https://apt.kitware.com) for the latest version of CMake.

Comment: Since the above is version-specific, here's a link to the updated directions from kitware: https://apt.kitware.com/

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install CMAKE in my WSL and I had the similar problem at the bootstrap stage as well, but this error disappeared once I installed the OpenSSL by using the command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

It seems to me the most likely reason in your case is that the OpenSSL package hasn't been properly installed. To test if it is that case, perhaps you could have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/a/61526) answer.