# Error trying to build NR-SLAM on WSL, Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS

Tags: command-line, 20.04, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed the [github](https://github.com/endomapper/NR-SLAM) to try to build and run NR SLAM. I downloaded OpenCV (version 4.4.0), Pangolin, mlpack-4.3.0, Boost, Eigen3.0, and had to update the kitware repository using this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line) to get the most recent cmake version.  When running `~/NR_SLAM$ ./build.sh`, the build suddenly stops with this error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/NR_SLAM/build'
make: *** [Makefile:159: all] Error 2
```

The only other error I could really find  was way above:

```
/home/myname/NR_SLAM/third_party/g2o/g2o/core/eigen_types.h:30:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
   30 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here..? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is the eigen3 development package (`libeigen3-dev`) installed on your system?

Comment: Yes it is! I used sudo apt-get libeigen3-dev to install eigen3.