# Unable to run make menuconfig

Tags: 12.04, make

When I am using the command make menuconfig, then its showing

```
sharath@sharath:~/openwrt$ make menuconfig
Checking 'working-make'... ok.
Checking 'case-sensitive-fs'... ok.
Checking 'getopt'... ok.
Checking 'fileutils'... ok.
Checking 'working-gcc'... ok.
Checking 'working-g++'... failed.
Checking 'ncurses'... failed.
Checking 'zlib'... failed.
Checking 'gawk'... failed.
Checking 'flex'... failed.
Checking 'unzip'... ok.
Checking 'bzip2'... ok.
Checking 'patch'... ok.
Checking 'perl'... ok.
Checking 'python'... ok.
Checking 'wget'... ok.
Checking 'gnutar'... ok.
Checking 'svn'... ok.
Checking 'gnu-find'... ok.
Checking 'getopt-extended'... ok.
Checking 'non-root'... ok.

Build dependency: Please install the GNU C++ Compiler (g++).
Build dependency: Please install ncurses. (Missing libncurses.so or ncurses.h)
Build dependency: Please install zlib. (Missing libz.so or zlib.h)
Build dependency: Please install GNU awk.
Build dependency: Please install flex.

Prerequisite check failed. Use FORCE=1 to override.
make: *** [tmp/.prereq-build] Error 1
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Most users don't install from source.  What are you trying to do here?  There may be an easier way to install what you are after.  If not you will need to install the dependences first. `sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses5 zlib1g gawk flex` then see what other errors you get.

Answer (score 7):

It fails because of missing dependencies. You need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk zlib1g libncurses5 g++ flex
```

After installing these packages your command should run through.

Comment: OP will need the *development* packages of those libraries `zlib1g-dev` and `libncurses5-dev`.

Comment: Indeed @DavidFoerster comment deserves to be an answer on its own. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Making menuconfig is requiring You to have developer's libraries of some packets that are used by a build You want to perform.

There is one of answers:
[How do I install ncurses header files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270381/how-do-i-install-ncurses-header-files)

Yeah, You can be not in need of ncurses binaries, but You do need it's developer's libraries. Something alike is about the rest of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

On kubuntu 16.04LTS I had a similar issue compiling openwrt, but no package existed that satisfied the specific issue with ncurses:

```
Build dependency: Please install ncurses. (Missing libncurses.so or ncurses.h)
```

The only way to fix it was to add the following repository to my sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

On kubuntu 16.04LTS
the answer from @MoonCactus have fixed ncurses problem, It's great.

but for

```
Build dependency: Please install ncurses. (Missing libncurses.so or ncurses.h)
```

you can try

```
aptitude install zlib1g-dev
```

follow the system masseges to downgrade

```
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     zlib1g-dev [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     zlib1g [1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 (now) -> 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4 (xenial)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  zlib1g
```

Comment: It seems you've got a copy-paste problem, you are talking about ncurses and installing a zlib package